# How to prevent unauthorized HTTP requests?

Tags: ios, http, authorization

I have some code in my iOS app like this:

```
URL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://urltomyapp.com/createaccount"];
ASIFormDataRequest *createAccountRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[createAccountRequest setPostValue:email forKey:@"email"];
[createAccountRequest setPostValue:password forKey:@"password"];
[createAccountRequest startAsynchronous];
```

In my server implementation, I simply take this information via self.request.get('email') and create an account, not doing any checks or anything. However, it seems that anyone can run the above piece of code easily (I mean all you'd need to do is copy the above code and put it into your own app, right?), all they'd need to know is the server address and they can attach any data they want to the request, and the server would go ahead and create an account for them.

How would I authorize requests to know that they are coming from my app and my app only? Is this a common concern? How do other products protect against this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a disclaimer.  I am certainly not **not** a web expert, nor am I a security expert.  In fact, the only reason I'm answering at all is because of the discussion in stackmonster's reply.

However, I do know that intercepting an SSL connection is exceptionally easy, especially if the user is complicit.

In general, though, I think the following is of some benefit.

You have to determine who/what you are trying to protect.  If you just want to protect the data in the communication between the app and the server, https will be just fine.  External snooping will be as effective (or ineffective) as snooping other SSL traffic.

However, if you are trying to protect your API (which your question seems to suggest), it is trivial for a user to see what commands you are sending (as you, yourself found out by using Charles).

So, do you want to prevent anyone from knowing the details of your API?  Do you want to just prevent DOS attacks, or only let valid users issue commands, or what?

You can then worry about authentication and authorizations (two different topics).  Maybe validating that the request comes from a known entity is enough.

Anyway, it is extremely difficult to give guidance because you first have to decide what your networking privacy goals are.

Then, if they are lofty, you are in for a lot of reading.

At some point, though, you have to decide what is crucial to your app/business, and what is not.  Just like any good software design, then create a set of requirements.  Then, prioritize them in some order (e.g., mandatory, essential, nice to have, can live without).

That will tell you if you need additional security, and what kind.

Most, however, find that it's not worth the time and investment to even lock all the doors and bar the windows (not to mention protecting the chimney, adding concrete to the walls, floors, and ceilings, building a safe-room, and hiring armed guards).

Comment: I'm not trying to be over-secure or paranoid. I think what I'm not understanding is this (as an example): I have a url in my server "createaccount" which requires two parameters to be sent with the request: email and password. This script does not require any authentication (I mean what could I possibly authenticate here), so it seems that any one (for no reason what so ever) can make a for loop with 10,000 iterations that sends a request to this url and creates 10,000 user accounts. Maybe this doesn't happen often, but what's preventing it from happening? Shouldn't I be worried about this?

Comment: Should you be worried?  Only if it matters.  In that case, you will have to employ some type of server-side measures to detect/prevent the behavior you don't want.  If you have a server port open to the internet, anyone can send you whatever they want.  If the standard server is not enough, you will have to employ server-side measures.  In the end, if someone is determined to abuse your server, it will cost you a lot in both time and money to defend.  I think most choose to put locks on the door, and wait to see if they have to do more.

Answer (score 2):

use HTTPS and put a cert inside your app to verify the client is allowed to talk to your server.

But trust me, its really not worth all that.  Using HTTPS is generally ok on its own.

Comment: I am using HTTPS, but how does that change anything?

Comment: if you use HTTPS, its not possible to sniff the traffic from your client to the server.  However, your server does in fact exist, so it can be called on the web.  If you deploy a cert to the client, only clients with your cert can talk to you.

Only way to prevent it.  But its really not that important, if you use HTTPS offending clients wont generally know HOW to talk to your server therefore they will error out.

Comment: I thought using HTTPS was just enabling a checkbox in your server and changing urls to use https:// instead of http://..? Can't someone still make requests to the https:// url? What will I have that they won't have?

Comment: of course they can but how will they know HOW to talk to your server?
Unless they know what URLS and params to send your server they can only try and DDOS you.  But even using a client cert doesnt stop that. 
If you want you can have an auth method that returns a special token to the client, but even then you wont know if the initial connection was from a trusted client without a cert.

If its that important to you use a cert, thats what they are for.

Comment: So should I make talking to my server less basic? For example my login script uses the url example.com/login and sends params for keys "email" and "password". I'm sure that's the first thing anyone would try. So there's the HOW part. And I'm sure it's not that hard to figure out the URLs for my app.

Comment: the URL is not exposed using HTTPS so even if its basic its unknown.  Like I said, you dont need 100% client security unless you do, in which case you use a cert, just like any secure app would require a cert on the client regardless if it was a mobile app or not.

Comment: and to answer you no, dont obfuscate your method calls, let true security measures take care of it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16129/discussion-between-mohabitar-and-stackmonster)

Comment: @stackmonster It IS possible (and quite easy) to sniff https traffic.  Simply set up a http proxy on your own machine, change the settings on your iDevice to use the proxy, and you can see the real data.  A simple app to do this is http://www.charlesproxy.com.

Comment: @JodyHagins but I thought that was the whole point of HTTPS and SSL? To prevent sniffing?

Comment: Incorrect, HTTPS traffic is encrypted before it leaves the device, proxy or no proxy.

Comment: Ok I just tested the Charles app and logged in to facebook..the data was NOT encrypted and I was able to see my facebook email AND password..looks like Jody was right..I don't understand what's going on though..

Comment: then its not an encrypted connection

Comment: it sound slike you tested this on your desktop.  What I said was - The traffic is encrypted BEFORE IT LEAVES THE DEVICE.  The OS be it desktop or mobile handles the encryption so someone would have to put your app on a jailbroken device to do this.  If proxies could magically decrypt HTTPS traffic there would be no point to HTTPS at all

Comment: @stackmonster Sorry, my friend, but you are misinformed.  Unless you do something more than just establishing an SSL connection, anyone can setup their device to use a proxy as an intermediary, and snoop the traffic.  Users can easily allow untrusted certificates, or even install a proxy-generated root certificate on their device.

Comment: @stackmonster, you're wrong.  It's trivial to sniff HTTPS connections by using a proxy.  [Here's how to set up an iOS device and Charles to sniff encrypted connections from iOS applications.](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/ssl-connections-from-within-iphone-applications/)

Comment: "trivial" - it is only _trivial_ if the user has ignored the obtrusive security warnings on their device and proceeded to accept the untrusted security certificate issued by the proxy.